# 'Not enough memory or recouces' in Outlook 2007, running on Windows Server 2008 Remote Desktop Services

Tags: windows-server-2008, outlook-2007, remote-desktop-services

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 running Remote Desktop Services.
Some user receives an error 'Not enough resources or memory' when trying to view address book in Outlook 2007. Also when trying to open a file in MS Word 2007.

Comment: Any more information you can provide like logs or system configuration, how many users are connected at once, something with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

We repaired Office 2007 installation in USER INSTALL mode, the problem is fixed.